# How to print data from an object and error [object Object] does not appear?

Tags: javascript

I have this program that as soon as it starts up, it asks you to enter the number of books that you want to register in the program and the number of authors that each book will have.
The program will ask you to register a name for each author, surname, age and nationality.
Once this is done, there is a button that shows all the books registered with their authors and the data of the books, and I have the problem that I am not able to show the data of the authors since only [object Object] appears.

Edit:
I have managed to print the `element.autores` by `console.log`, without the error obejct object appearing but I am not able to get it out through a `document.write` or something similar, here I leave a screenshot of how it should appear:
[image: 1]

And if I try to put `elements.autores.nombre` to print only the name, it appears undefined both in the `console.log` and in the `document.write`
Here my code:

javascript:

```js
var biblioteca = new Array();

function libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial) {
    
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autores = autores;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.editorial = editorial;
    
}
    
function autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.aepellidos = apellidos;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
    
}
    
window.onload = function () {

    document.getElementById("mostrar").onclick = Mostrar;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarlibro;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarautor;
}

function insertarlibro() {
    var autores = new Array();
    var titulo = prompt("Insertar el nombre del titulo del libro");
    var anyo = parseInt(prompt("Año"));
    var editorial = prompt("Inserta su editorial");
    var numautores = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos autores vas a insertar"));
    for (let i = 0; i < numautores; i++) {
        let autor = insertarautor();
        autores.push(autor);
    }
    
    var registrohecho = new libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial);
    
    return registrohecho;
    
}
    
console.log(insertarlibro);
    
    
function insertarautor() {
    
    var nombre = prompt("Insertar el nombre del autor").toUpperCase();
    var apellidos = prompt("Insertar el apellidos del autor").toUpperCase();
    var edad = parseInt(prompt("Edad"));
    var nacionalidad = prompt("¿De que pais es el autor?");
    var registrohecho = new autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad);
    
    return registrohecho;

}

console.log(insertarautor);

var numlibros = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos libros vas a insertar"));
for (let i = 0; i < numlibros; i++) {
    var insertalibro = insertarlibro();
    biblioteca.push(insertalibro);
    
}


function Mostrar() {
    
    biblioteca.forEach(element => {
        console.log("Error" + JSON.stringify(element.autores));
        var muestra = "Nombre del libro:" + element.titulo + " autores: " + element.autores + " Año en el que se publico: " + element.anyo + " Editorial: " + element.editorial;
        document.write(muestra);
    });
}
```

And the html part:

```html
<div id="insertar">
    <input type="button" value="Insertar">
</div>
<div id="mostrar">
    <input type="button" value="Mostrar">
</div>
```

Comment: You definitely don't want `document.write(muestra)`; not entirely sure what you're trying to do there. `muestra` is a string and does not have `innerHTML`, the target of `innerHTML` should be a DOM element.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have changed the code, look at it again putting json stringly was an error on my part this is how I have the code currently and I still have the same error. And what I try is to print the data of the books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get `element.autores`, which is an array. To get e.g. get the `nombre`, you wold have to acces it with `element.autores[0].nombre`.

So your code to output all books (with authors) would be something like this:

```
biblioteca.forEach(element => {
    var muestra = "Nombre del libro:" + element.titulo + " autores: ";
    element.autores.forEach(author => {
        muestra += `nombre: ${author.nombre}, aepellidos: ${author.aepellidos}, edad: ${author.edad}, nacionalidad: ${author.nacionalidad} `;
    })
    muestra += "Año en el que se publico: " + element.anyo + " Editorial: " + element.editorial;
    document.write(muestra);
});
```

Comment: If I put "elements.autores.nombre" but I get undefined

Comment: Because you are pushing the result of the `insertarautor()` function, you are getting an array, so therefor you have to access it with `element.autores[0].nombre`. So if you loop over it, it should work.